# Not able to navigate to certain URL in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, whitelist

I'm not able to navigate to a certain URL when I'm using the following command:

```
window.location.href = "http://google.com";
```

In my cordova config.xml file I already specified to access to all sources using the default cordova setting with the wildcard:

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
```

Here is what location prints to the console:

```
Location {replace: function, assign: function, ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList, origin: "file://", hash: ""…}
ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList
assign: function () { [native code] }
hash: ""
host: ""
hostname: ""
href: "file:///android_asset/www/index.html"
origin: "file://"
pathname: "/android_asset/www/index.html"
port: ""
protocol: "file:"
reload: function reload() { [native code] }
replace: function () { [native code] }
search: ""
toString: function toString() { [native code] }
valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }
__proto__: Location
```

I'm running my application in Android with the cordova 5.1.1 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, the default access settings aren't enough, i don't really know why, but i think i know how to patch this.

Try to install this plugin :

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

And then, in your config.xml, add this line

```
<allow-navigation href="http://google.com/*" />
```

Compile again and tell me how it's going on ! :)

Comment: This works. Thank you very much! Even if we don't know why the default is not enough :)

Comment: Had the same issue. I don't wanna say something wrong, but i think it comes from a recent update of cordova. I'm glad it works for you now ! :)

Comment: In my case when I set 'allow-navigation' to 'http://url.com/*' then it was showing an error stating navigation is not allowed for 'https://url.com/*' and when I set for 'https://url.com/*' it was showing the same error that it cannot allow 'http://url.com/*'.
So I included both the tags. <allow-navigation href="http://url.com/*" /> and <allow-navigation href="https://url.com/*" />, it worked.
I didn't install the plugin.